# Creating subquery using IN

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a question on making a good subquery for this problem

Let's say we have a table users, and links.

```
users
+++++++++
id name
1  name1
2  name2
3  name3
+++++++++
```

---

```
links
+++++++++
id link
1  link1
2  link1
3  link1
+++++++++
```

And lets say i have a relationship table like this

```
name_links
++++++++++++
uid  lid
1    1,3
2    1,2,3
3    2
++++++++++++
```

I know this is not the most used method to do this. I posted another questions on suggestions on this method. If you have any suggestions here is the link.

[mysql query normal relationship table vs concatenated realtionship table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349216/mysql-query-normal-relationship-table-vs-concatenated-realtionship-table)

But using this scheme, i can't get the query to work. The query i came up with is the following:

```
SELECT link 
FROM links 
WHERE links.id
    IN
    (
        SELECT lid
        FROM name_links
        WHERE uid=1
    )
```

I am doing this with the right syntax and quotes, but i only get one row, the first row. So for example using this same query i only get link1 as result. I need to get link1 and link3.

This is driving me nuts, i can really need some help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  link
FROM    name_links
JOIN    links
ON      FIND_IN_SET(id, lid)
WHERE   uid = 1
```

As I mentioned in the [**answer to your previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349216/mysql-query-normal-relationship-table-vs-concatenated-realtionship-table/2349278#2349278), `FIND_IN_SET` is unsargable.